# Could not find a part of the path '\\\WebApplication1\bin\WebApp\lication1.ddl'.'

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

'"Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Dushyant\Desktop...... \sample-asp-net-mvc-master\WebApplication1\bin\WebApp\lication1.ddl'."

I'm working on an Asp.net MVC project. When I'm trying to run that application then I see an error message"[image]

the Project Link : https://github.com/Dushyantsingh-ds/sample-asp-net-mvc

Comment: [Map that monstrous folder name](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/map-a-network-drive-in-windows-10-29ce55d1-34e3-a7e2-4801-131475f9557d) to something like W:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paths in VS are limited to 255 characters.  Move your project to C:\test and see if it works then.

Comment: A new error is occurring: The CodeDom provider type Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be located. (C:\sample-asp-net-mvc-master\WebApplication1\web.config line 87)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below option which could solve your problem:

**Option 1**: Try to delete your existing `bin` and `obj` folder then rebuild again

**Option 2**: Reduce the folder path of  your application, put your application in `c:/youapplication/`

It should solve your problem